# How to get Less to work on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, less

I'm trying to use Less (http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.fr.html) as an Eclipse plugin and I can't get it to work. It doesn't generate any errors but it also doesn't generate any results.

I've tried executing less from the command line and this works fine (I installed through npm install less --global.

My Run configuration is

- LESS command: `/usr/local/bin/lessc`
- Input file: `/My-Project/src/main/webapp/assets/css/less/twbs/bootstrap.less`
- Output file: `/My-Project/src/main/webapp/assets/css/stylesheet.css`

When I run the command, it almost immediately returns but the expected file doesn't show up (including after refresh)

Any suggestions on how to get it to work?

Comment: you probably don't need this anymore but did you try lessc.cmd that was my problem